# handle the result form the gallery

Tags: java, android-studio, imageview, image-gallery

i searched for many days about `how to get image from gallery` i admit that i found alot of codes but no one worked .
i have this code now and when i hit the button and choose an image the program stop "unfortunately app has stopped " . 
any help will be appreciated ...
this is the code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
    });
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Below is the working solution of choosing a picture from library or capturing one from camera and using it in a imageview.

Source : SO

Firstly initialize the imageview in `onCreate` method. Then call `selectimage` function through any button's `onClick` event and that's it.

```
//functions to select image from the device
    private void selectImage() {
        final CharSequence[] items = {"Take Photo","Choose from Library", "Cancel" };
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(signature_new.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
                } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(
                            Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),
                            SELECT_FILE);
                } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
                Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);

                File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                        System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

                FileOutputStream fo;
                try {
                    destination.createNewFile();
                    fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
                    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                    fo.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                imageF.setImage(ImageSource.bitmap(thumbnail));

            } else if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                try {

                    Bitmap bm=decodeUri(selectedImageUri);
                    imageViewF.setImage(ImageSource.bitmap(bm));
                    //uploadbm=bm;
                    //dialog_dimension();
                }
                catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks man a lot and i need some help because something went wrong and there is some samples not ok >